# Hiding fields in joined report

Tags: reporting, lightning

I have a joined report where I want to hide some of the fields because they are only used for a total.  These totals are only for the Master object however they are showing up on the details as well (as they should with a standard query).  However in many reporting tools, I could hide that field and display it on the group by section change of the master object.

All this duplicate data from the parent on the child details is kinda distracting

See attached to see if this is somehow possible.  If it is, how do I do it?

[image: report issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you edit a cross-block formula you can define this:

> **'Where will this formula be displayed?'**
>
> This formula calculation will be displayed in the report at the level you select.
>
> - All summary levels
> - Grand summary only
> - Grouping 1: Account Name
> - Grouping 2: Idea Number

Comment: so I have to create a formula to summarize the data on the child level?

Comment: got it!  Perfect!

Comment: You mentioned joined report, so I assumed you are using them already

Comment: @tjcinnamon You can be interested in [Passing Variables to Joined Reports in JavaScript](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/114517/12440)

Comment: I'll look into it.  Maybe I can incorporate a report into a lightning component?

Comment: I'm not sure. We are not using a lightning interface yet.