# Cross filter and custom report link

Tags: reporting, custom, filters

In custom report link, I can substitute the values in the filter using pv0, pv1 & so on....

but what if my filter rules include cross filer ? Will I still be able to use pv0, pv1 etc.

E.g.
Expire date equal 01/10/2016 --> pv0
And customer without member cards
issued date less than 01/01/2016 --> pv1 ???

How do I create a report link that can include cross filter ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Reports dynamic parameter `pv0`, `pv1`..etc supports the Report filter.

> We cannot substitute Cross Object Filter by those values.

For example, below report has 2 filters, First one on Account Name and Second one in Last Name which under cross object filter "Accounts with Contacts".

[image: Report]

> After, trying to substitute those values by `pv0=AB&pv1=Mill` through parameter, the Last Name filter still showing blank.

[image: report param]

Comment: there is an article on the web : http://www.verticalcoder.com/2014/06/03/url-hacking-cross-filter-reports/  but it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Please follow my instructions on how to [Passing Variables to Joined Reports in JavaScript](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/114517/12440) - all you need from there is to look at the screenshot, and follow 
[zachelrath's instructions how to get runReportJson string from here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/8998/12440). You would prefer parsed `Form Data` parameters with values. Next, account filter and cross filter with subfilter from Santanu Boral's answer should be looking like this: `?pv0=AB&ptable0=ACCOUNT_ID&ocond0=w&rtable0=Contact&rtablecol0=Account&sfpc0_0=LastName&sfpn0_0=co&sfpv0_0=Mill` - as you can see it always has the same parameter names, so you have to look at `Form Data` for your report and replace the values with what you find in there.

**Note** As Daniel said in his blog post, you have to ***resave your report without cross filter*** to have it working.